# If $X \times Y$ are topological spaces, then $\overline {A \times B} = \overline A \times \overline B$ and $int(A \times B) = int(A) \times int(B)$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

This seems just like trivial frizzo flazzo, but never the less can someone check my work

**Problem**: If $X \times Y$ are topological spaces, $A \subset X, B \subset Y$ then $\overline {A \times B} = \overline A \times \overline B$ and $int(A \times B) = int(A) \times int(B)$

Let $\tau$ denote the product topology on $X \times Y$. Let $z = (x,y)$. Suffices to check basic open sets.

1. $z \in \overline{A \times B} \implies \forall U \times V \in \tau, z \in U \times V$, then $(U \times V) \cap (A \times B) \neq \varnothing $

$\implies (U \cap A) \times (V \cap B) \neq  \varnothing \implies U \cap A \neq \varnothing, V \cap B \neq \varnothing$$ \implies x \in \overline A$ and $y \in \overline B$.

Therefore $z \in \overline A \times \overline B$.

The other direction is just pure reconstruction thus omitted.

2. $z \in int(A \times B) \implies \forall U \times V \in \tau, z \in U \times V$, then $U \times V \subseteq A \times B $

$\implies $ $U \subseteq A$ and $U \subseteq B \implies x \in int(A)$ and $y \in int(B)$ so $z\in int(A) \times int(B)$

The other direction is again reconstruction therefore omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the closure, the direction you do should be a bit different:

Suppose $(x,y) \in \overline{A \times B}$, and we want to see that $x \in \overline{A}$ and also $y \in \overline{B}$. This would show $\overline{A \times B} \subseteq \overline{A} \times \overline{B}$.

So to see that $x \in \overline{A}$ you should pick an arbitrary $U$ open that contains $x$, and show that $U \cap A \neq \emptyset$. Note that $U \times Y$ is open in $X \times Y$ and contains $(x,y)$. So $(U \times Y) \cap (A \times B)$ is non-empty, which implies that $U \cap A \neq \emptyset$, as required.

For $y \in \overline{B}$, do a similar thing with $X \times V$.

Main difference: you don't do these two inclusions at the same time, but one at the time, which is more correct. It also generalises to infinite products (if you have done those yet).

For the other direction, $\overline{A} \times \overline{B} \subseteq \overline{A \times B}$, start with $(x,y) \in \overline{A} \times \overline{B}$, and we want to show that $(x,y) \in \overline{A \times B}$, so pick any basic neighbourhood $U \times V$ that contains $(x,y)$, etc. Then you can do the reverse of your proof.

For the interior, one direction is easy: $\operatorname{int}(A) \times \operatorname{int}(B)$ is open and a subset of $A \times B$. So as the interior is the largest open subset of a set, $\operatorname{int}(A) \times \operatorname{int}(B) \subseteq \operatorname{int}(A \times B)$.

For the other inclusion, pick $(x,y) \in \operatorname{int}(A \times B)$, so there is some basic open subset $U \times V$ with $(x,y) \in U \times V \subseteq A \times B$. Now, because all sets in the product are non-empty (!) we have $x \in U \subseteq A$ and $y \in V \subseteq B$, showing that $(x,y) \in \operatorname{int}(A) \times \operatorname{int}(B)$, as required.

Comment: I will use your approach from now on